# Setting constraint in Gurobi model with a rolling lower and upper bound

Tags: python, constraints, gurobi, continuous

My gurobi model simulates the functioning of a Battery. However, I am wondering whether it is possible to set a rolling lower and upper bound for a semicontinuous variable. Below is an example that shows the (constant) upper and lower bound which I would like to take a different value per interval.  T is the total amount of intervals.

`P_bat_discharge = m.addVars(T, vtype = gp.GRB.SEMICONT, name="P_bat_discharge", lb = x, ub = y)`

I am wondering if it is possible to specify a varying lower and upper bound per interval that is modelled, can't find it anywhere but maybe any of you knows a clever trick.

Something like:

`P_bat_discharge = m.addVars(T, vtype = gp.GRB.SEMICONT, name="P_bat_discharge", lb = x[t] for t in range (T), ub = y[t] for t in range (T))`

Comment: I am not an expert in Gurobi's syntax, but couldn't you just build the constraints in a loop over `t`, specifying the correct bounds for each `t`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of values for the `lb` and `ub` attributes upon creation of the variables.  Here is simple example that tries to capture what you want to achieve:

```
import gurobipy as gp
T = 3
lbdata = [1,2,3]
ubdata = [4,5,6]

m = gp.Model()
m.addVars(3, vtype=gp.GRB.SEMICONT, lb=lbdata[0:T], ub=ubdata[0:T])
m.write('a.lp')
```

On my machine this generates the LP

```
Minimize
  0 C0 + 0 C1 + 0 C2
Subject To
Bounds
 1 <= C0 <= 4
 2 <= C1 <= 5
 3 <= C2 <= 6
Semi-continuous
 C0 C1 C2
End
```